# Can we install both Tableau Public and Tableau Desktop (trial version) simultaneously?

Tags: tableau-api

I am new to Tableau and is looking forward to explore it for a POC.Since Tableau is licensed software I am looking to judiciously use my trial version.  Is it possible that I install tableau public on my machine and later I install  tableau desktop (trial version) on same machine using the same corporate email ID(since tableau supports only work email id), Will it work fine?? Won't my tableau public installation affect the tableau desktop trial version installation.

Also, I read description about tableau public that it is a developer tool as well as sharing tool. So it will have server. I mean while installing the tableau public both desktop & server needs to be installed on same machine or is there any specific software requirement for the same.

Comment: I can share my experience. Since I'm a student, I actually took the student version of tableau first, which allows me to use it for free for one year. And then I was attending some online course and for that I installed tableau public and started using it and till date it's working fine

Comment: What do you require for using the student version of tableau

Comment: The student email ID provided by the university

Comment: You have installed tableau public both desktop and server on same machine?

Comment: It requires no approval of any sorts. I just gave in my student email ID, verified it,  downloaded the software and started using it.

Comment: Yes, I've both tableau public and the desktop student version on the same machine

Comment: I hope there is no server configurations required for Tableau Server

Answer (score 0):

There is no interaction between Tables Public and Tableau Desktop if they are installed on the same machine. Tableau Public will remain free and will keep working; Tableau desktop will, eventually, need a licence key and the trial version will expire.

Tableau Public does not require any other installations. It can be used to publish to *public* servers hosted by Tableau online. But you don't have to install anything locally and you can't control anything much on the public servers.

A lot of people publish interesting Tableau visualisations on public.tabeleau.com which is, in effect, a huge repository of open-access Tableau visualisations.

Answer (score 0):

I have extensively used Tableau. Both Tableau And Tableau Desktop are same in function wise.The Tableau Desktop is data visualization software that lets you see and understand data in minutes. The professional version of this can transform, process and store huge volumes of data.Once the trial period is over you need to move from desktop to pro version.

The Tableau Public is essentially a free version of Tableau visualization software. It allows you to use most of the software functions. You can create visualizations and connect to CSV, Text and Excel documents. However, the largest difference is that Tableau Public does not allow you to save your workbooks locally. But you can publish them over tableau official gallery.